# Update date to 1st day of the month in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update

How would I go about updating the dates in a MySQL table to the first day of the month?

For example, the data looks like this:

```
1   2013-01-13
2   2013-02-11
3   2013-02-01
4   2013-01-30
5   2013-03-27
```

...and I would like it to look like this...

```
1   2013-01-01
2   2013-02-01
3   2013-02-01
4   2013-01-01
5   2013-03-01
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can convert it to string to get the year and month and concatenate it with `01`.

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     dateField = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dateField, '%Y-%m-'), '01')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee9ed/1)

Comment: Apparently just `DATE_FORMAT(dateField, '%Y-%m-01')` works too

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE tableName SET date = DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(date)-1 DAY)
```

[Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)